# Prometheus Alertmanger delete All silences using curl. REST API

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

How can I delete all the existing silences in Prometheus Alertmanger using the curl.

I tried using this but getting `404 page not found`

```
curl -X DELETE http://alerts.example.org:9093/api/v1/silence/<silenceId>
```

How can I delete all the silences? something like

`curl -X DELETE http://alerts.example.org:9093/api/v1/silence/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete all the silences with just a curl command but you can list all the silences ids with the following command:

```
curl -X GET http://alerts.example.org:9093/api/v1/silences | jq --raw-output '.data[].id'

9e2d7680-8543-447f-9776-db513fa88b3b
1e37bb70-a6ae-4247-b748-fd7aee838140
6dac91c5-08a7-4a14-8dac-7137c61ae94d
```

And then delete using your "curl -X DELETE" command.

Comment: Could you approve the answer? Thanks.